# O notation verification?

Tags: notation

I see examples online that proves that if $f(n)\in O(h(n))$ and $g(n)\in O(h(n))$, then $f(n)+g(n)\in O(h(n))$ using the definition of O notation.

However, if given $f(n)\in O(h(n))$ and $g(n)\in O(h(n))$, then how can I prove/disprove:

$$f(n)*g(n)\in O(h(n))?$$

So far, I have gotten to defining (from the definition of O notation):

$$f(n)\ \le\ c_1h(n)\ for\ n\ \geq\ n_0^\prime$$
$$g(n)\ \le\ c_2h(n)\ for\ n\ \geq\ n_0^{\prime\prime}$$

where $c_1, c_2, n_0^\prime, n_0^{\prime\prime}$ are all positive constants, but I'm not quite sure what to do next. Do I multiply the constants together?

Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: Of course this is not true. For example, $h(n)$ is $O(h(n))$ for obvious reasons, but $h(n) \times h(n)$ will definitely not be $O(h(n))$ if $h(n)$ is going to infinity, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You cannot prove it, because it is false.*

Counterexample: $f(n)=g(n)=h(n)=n$.

Then clearly $f(n)\in O(h(n))$, $g(n)\in O(h(n))$, but $f(n)g(n) = n^2 \not\in O(h(n)) = O(n)$.